# Is AWS java lambda layer automatically starts JVM?

Tags: python, java, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers, aws-lambda-extensions

I am new to aws layers/extensions. Is AWS java lambda layer automatically starts JVM? or DO we need to manually start? I am trying to create java lambda layer and call the methods from lambda function, however I am trying to call java method from lambda I am getting `Runtime exited with error: signal: segmentation fault`
Python code (lambda):

```
def call_java_method()
    #jpype.addClassPath(JAR) - Not sure what path I should give here?
    class_name = 'com.java.example.SampleJavaClass'
    my_class = JClass(class_name)

    instance = my_class()
    result = instance.sampleMethod()
    print(result)
```

Java Code:

```
package com.java.example;

public class SampleJavaClass {
    public String sampleMethod() {
        return "sampleMethod() called!";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is now the third or fourth post you've made about a Python Lambda using Java.  You've yet to explain why you want something this difficult.  A Python Lambda will not have a Java runtime by default.  A Java Lambda will not have a Python runtime by default.  Whatever it is you're trying to do Lambda does not seem like a good solution.  To use `JClass` you'd need to include an entire Java JVM in your Python package.

Comment: Thanks for answering again. "You've yet to explain why you want something this difficult" - I need this because of legacy reasons i.e., we have a legacy python lambda and and legacy java package. Now we need to use java package in python lambda. I can't convert java package into python and python lambda into java lambda. If you know any better way to achieve (other than creating java lambda and use aws lambda invoke method ) this please let me know.

Comment: I truly feel that you'd be better off with an EC2 environment.  You could install Java *and* Python on it and, depending on the code, have one call the other as appropriate.  Lambda's are intentionally focused and not as general purpose as you need.  The EC2 would expose a service out of either the Python side or the Java side that would be a network call for the outside world.  Otherwise you need to expose the Java functionality as it's own Lambda and have the Python Lambda call it.  That's possible but I'd argue harder to build and maintain.

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous comment, it's a legacy code that deployed as python lambda. It's nearly not possible to change this. For maintenance reasons I can't create new lambda for java. So I am trying to write an java lambda extension and use that in python lambda. As I am new to aws lambda extensions facing difficulties on achieving this.

Comment: Can you use a Docker container?  I just don't see how you'll be able to use a standard Lambda.  Then you could package everything you need into a single place and use things like `JClass`.

Comment: I am able to package all the java code and deploy it as aws layer. And It got extracted class files in `/op`t folder. Now I am trying to use these class files in python using Jpype. However I am not sure what classpath I should give here `jpype.addClassPath`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254111/discussion-between-stdunbar-and-lakshmiravali-rimmalapudi).

Answer (score 0):

In AWS Lambda, the Java runtime is automatically started for you when you invoke a Lambda function written in Java. You do not need to manually start the JVM (Java Virtual Machine).

To create a Java Lambda layer and call methods from a Lambda function, there are a few steps you need to follow:

> 1. Build the Java code: Compile your Java code and package it into a JAR file. In your case, the JAR file should contain the
>    com.java.example.SampleJavaClass class.
> 2. Create a Lambda Layer: In the AWS Management Console or using the AWS CLI/SDKs, create a Lambda Layer. Upload the JAR file containing
>    your Java code to the layer.
> 3. Configure your Lambda function: When creating or configuring your Lambda function, add the created Lambda Layer to the function's
>    layers. This makes the Java classes and methods in the layer available
>    to your Lambda function.
> 4. Write the Lambda function code: In your Python code (Lambda function), you can use the jpype library to call Java methods. Make
>    sure to import the required jpype modules and initialize the JVM. The
>    specific path to add as a classpath depends on the structure of your
>    Lambda function and the location of the Java classes and JAR files.
>    You can experiment with different paths to find the correct one.

```
import jpype

def call_java_method():
    jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath())

    # Add the necessary classpath to load the Java class
    jpype.addClassPath('/path/to/your/jar/file.jar')

    # Import and use the Java class
    from com.java.example import SampleJavaClass

    instance = SampleJavaClass()
    result = instance.sampleMethod()
    print(result)

    jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

Make sure to replace `/path/to/your/jar/file.jar` with the correct path to your JAR file containing the `com.java.example.SampleJavaClass`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. This is similar to what I am doing currently. However, Is there any better way to start JVM other than with `jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath())` from python code?